# How to resolve registered services(worker objects) in an android service using mvvmcross?

Tags: c#, android, mvvmcross, application-lifecycle

I'm trying to use mvvmcross in a android service, this is the code :

```
public interface IMyWorkerObject
{
    void ShowNotificationIcon();
}

[Service]
public class MyAndroidService : Service
{
    private Thread myThread;
    public override void OnCreate()
    {
        myThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                do
                {
                    var myWorkerObject = Mvx.Resolve<IMyWorkerObject>();
                    myWorkerObject.ShowNotificationIcon();    
                    Thread.Sleep(10000);
                } while (true);
            });
        myThread.IsBackground = true;
        myThread.Start();
        base.OnCreate();
    }
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
    public override void OnDestroy()
    {
        if (myThread != null)
        {
            if (myThread.IsAlive)
                myThread.Abort();
            myThread = null;
        }
    }
    public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

and I have this code in my app.cs

```
public class App : MvxApplication
{
    // ... some code ...
    public override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize();

        //Initializing Plugins..
        PluginLoader.Instance.EnsureLoaded();

        //Initializing Work Objects..
        var services = CreatableTypes()
            .EndingWith("Service");

        // start android service
        var context = Application.Context;
        var intent = new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(MyAndroidService ));
        context.StartService(intent);

        //Initializing Start Navigation
        RegisterAppStart<MainViewModel>();
    }

    // ... some code ...
```

}

everything works fine until I fully close the application, because of returning    `StartCommandResult.Sticky` 
the android service restarts but throws an exception at `var myWorkerObject = Mvx.Resolve<IMyWorkerObject>();` in the `OnCreate` method :

> Error : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object at
>   Cirrious.CrossCore.Mvx.Resolve[IMyWorkerObject] () [0x00000] in
>   :0  at App1.MyAndroidService.b__0 ()
>   [0x00000] in :0

what am i doing wrong, or better say is there any samples on how to use android services with mvvmcross?

Comment: Take a look at the questions and answers on http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmvvmcross%5D+ioc+background+service - but also do look at the issues on MvvmCross github - there are some tricky threading issues which can be hard to avoid.

Comment: I generally try to avoid doing my own threads whenever possible and make use of async/await.  I've had trouble in the past with simple tasks that ended up"just working" when I converted them to async/await.

Comment: I'm also seeing this error, did you ever find a solution?